# Dúvida com relacionamentos N to N ou 1 to N

Tags: c#

Dado o seguinte cenário. Tenho 1 tabela de usuário e uma de login, por exemplo. Preciso criar minha classe de domínio que mapeia essas entidades do BD. Na tabela de login, eu recebo o IDUsuario. Como fica na minha model esse relacionamento?

```
[Table("Usuario")]
    public class Usuario
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int IdUsuario { get; set; }
        public string NMUsuario { get; set; }
        public string Senha { get; set; }
    }

[Table("Login")]
    public class Login
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int IdLogin { get; set; }
        public DateTime DtLogin { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }?????????
    }
```

É isso mesmo que coloquei, uma Collection? E na tabela usuário, apenas um virtual IdUsuario?

Comment: Por que precisa uma coleção de usuários? Não é apenas um usuário que faz o *login*? Ou eu não entendi o que é esta tabela?

Comment: @bigown, isso, em realidade não sabia o que colocar e postei como exemplo apenas para saber se é isso ou não. Perdido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando seu código acima, e entendendo que você está usando Entity Framework Code First. Somente corrigi o seu código, entendendo também que você quer manter um registro de todos os logins dos usuarios, se ele entrar no sistema vai gerar um registro.

```
public class Usuario
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } //Vai ser autoincrement, padrão do entity
    public string NMUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Login> Logins { get; set; } //Navigation para ja pegar os registros da tabela login ao consultar os usuarios.
}

public class Login
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; } //Sequencial somente para efeito de key
    public DateTime DtLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; } //Aqui se faz a referencia
}
```

Lembrando que você também tem que adicionar as duas tabelas no Context.

Answer (score 2):

Não, não é preciso usar uma `Collection`. Isso vai fazer com que a relação de `Login` para `Usuarios` seja 1-N.

A relação precisa ser 1-1, então só precisa de uma propriedade que represente **um `Usuario`** dentro de um `Login`.

```
[Table("Login")]
public class Login
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int IdLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtLogin { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Já vi posts no SOen, com duas respostas marcadas. Aqui não posso fazer o mesmo? As duas resposta atende, vai depender de como eu vou utilizar e não quero punir ninguém.

Comment: Não dá. Nem aqui, nem no SOen. E, na verdade, a outra resposta cria uma relação 1-N, o que não parece ser o caso da sua pergunta.

Comment: Cara, eu vou caçar e depois te mostro um post com duas resposta marcadas no SOen. Mas isso é irrelevante, creio que você tem razão, mas ainda não testei tudo. Qualquer coisa, a resposta que melhor atender eu marco.